# Distinct() on Class, anonymus type and SelectListItem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-entities, distinct

I want to select all categories from a webservice. The webservice does not have a method for that, so I have to get all products, then select all categories that these products are in. When I recieve the data from the webservice, I make WebServiceProduct (ID, Name, etc) and WebServiceCategory (ID, Name, etc) objects of it.

This does not work:

```
        IQueryable<SelectListItem> categories = (from p in webserviceProductRepository.GetProducts()
                                                 from c in p.Categories
                                                 select new SelectListItem
                                                 {
                                                     Value = c.ID.ToString(),
                                                     Text = c.Name
                                                 }).Distinct().OrderBy(c => c.Text);
```

But it works when I first select it as a anonymus type:

```
        var foo = (from p in webserviceProductRepository.GetProducts()
                   from c in p.Categories
                   select new
                   {
                       ID = c.ID.ToString(),
                       Name = c.Name
                   }).Distinct().OrderBy(c => c.Name);

        IQueryable<SelectListItem> categories = from c in foo
                                                select new SelectListItem
                                                {
                                                    Value = c.ID.ToString(),
                                                    Text = c.Name
                                                };
```

I have also tried with a IEqualityComparer and overrided Equals and GetHashCode to check on WebServiceCategory.ID, but it does not work either.

So my question are, why is Distinct() working better on a anonymus type than on my WebServiceCategory object and SelectListItem?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "...does not work?"

Comment: It does return all WebServiceCategories, not just the distinct ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anonymous types have value equality. Reference types have reference equality. LINQ to Entities is following the default semantics for the types. But overriding `Equals` or implementing `IEquatable` won't work, because LINQ to Entities queries are translated to SQL, and LINQ to Entities cannot translate arbitrary C# code to SQL. Note that the overloads of, e.g., `Distinct` which take a comparer [aren't supported in L2E](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738550%28VS.100%29.aspx).

You have one workaround already, in your second code example. Another would be to group by an anonymous type:

```
var categories = from p in webserviceProductRepository.GetProducts()
                 from c in p.Categories
                 group c by new { Id = c.ID, Name = c.Name } into g
                 order by g.Key.Name
                 select new SelectListItem
                 {
                     Value = g.Key.Id.ToString(),
                     Text = g.Key.Name
                 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried implementing `IEquatable<T>` on `SelectListItem`?

Comment: No, I have not, will try that later.

Answer (score 0):

I think, its an IQueryable object and IEqualityComparer's wont work for this object. Maybe this will help

```
IQueryable<SelectListItem> categories = (from p in webserviceProductRepository.GetProducts()
                                         from c in p.Categories.Distinct()
                                         orderby c.Name
                                         select new SelectListItem
                                         {
                                             Value = c.ID.ToString(),
                                             Text = c.Name
                                         });
```

Comment: I think, If web service - or repository does not distinct values via this code. You have to get values to memory, after distinct values. Whats the 'foo' type when you use anonymous types?